# How to troubleshoot a plugin while developing in Jenkins?

Tags: java, debugging, jenkins, plugins

I'm developing a plugin from scratch, (Using `HelloWorldBuilder` as an example) but I can't seem to understand how to troubleshoot it. For example, I've written the following code.

The plugin is not displayed in the Build Steps although no error is seen during the start of Jenkins (in the console or web management of Jenkins) using hpi:run.

How can I troubleshoot why the plugin is not displayed?

```
public class MyConsole extends Builder {

    @Extension
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor {

        public DescriptorImpl(){
            load();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isApplicable(Class aClass) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDisplayName() {
            return "Tzach123";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Changing to the following **did** cause the plugin to display in the Build section, but, I still don't know how to troubleshoot it:

```
public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder>
```